# control over Vertex AI annotation

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, annotations, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai

In the Google Vertex AI platform, the configuration of labelling the data set is decided by the vertex AI itself, ie. for example the color which is given to the bounding box while labelling is decided by vertex ai, what if I want to assign the color as my preference? I couldn't see any option to change the annotation color and also tried to feed externally labelled files to the vertex ai and it shows an error as there is no field named color;

```
{
  "imageGcsUri": "gs://cloud-ai-platform-5100f6e6-d2e6-4966-869e-ba22a09ef85a/bg_MAX_0002.JPG",
  "boundingBoxAnnotations": [
    {
      "displayName": "abc",
      "xMin": 0.07510431154381085,
      "xMax": 0.34492350486787204,
      "yMin": 0.1022964509394572,
      "yMax": 0.4384133611691023,
      "annotationResourceLabels": {
        "aiplatform.googleapis.com/annotation_set_name": "3765893295830466560"
      }
    },
    {
      "displayName": "pqr",
      "xMin": 0.6801112656467315,
      "xMax": 0.9318497913769124,
      "yMin": 0.1503131524008351,
      "yMax": 0.6367432150313153,
      "annotationResourceLabels": {
        "aiplatform.googleapis.com/annotation_set_name": "3765893295830466560"
      }
    },
    {
      "displayName": "xyz",
      "xMin": 0.15438108484005564,
      "xMax": 0.6620305980528511,
      "yMin": 0.605427974947808,
      "yMax": 0.906054279749478,
      "annotationResourceLabels": {
        "aiplatform.googleapis.com/annotation_set_name": "3765893295830466560"
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataItemResourceLabels": {
    
  }
}
```

Given above is an example label generated by vertex ai and it doesn't contain any color information even though I've labelled in multiple colors.
So my question is how can we get control over the color feature of the labelling system in vertex AI?

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the docs there does not seem to be a way to set a color for labels, perhaps because it can be difficult to manage when labels get added or disappear and come back.

Fun fact:
The docs actually show an example where tomato is labeled as red, but then cheese is labeled green while salad is labeled yellow...